# Rx Android how do I check 204 code in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a request call which can return 200 if an user has been subscribed to an event,  204 if the user is not subscribed or 404 if the event no longer exist.

I'm using retrofit 2 and Observables for calling the server.

how can I check If I have a code 200 or 204?

If I got a 404 I know it is an error and I easily deal with it, but I the response is different I don't know how to get the actual code.

```
mApiEvents.isSubscribed(idEvent, uniqueId )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(getLifecycleProvider())
                .flatMap( data-> {

                    return  ?? //How do I check if I got 200 or 204?

                 }
                .subscribe(new LifecycleObserver<Boolean>(){

                   @Override
                   public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {      
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {

                       //404 or another error
                   }
               }
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it, at the end the solution is quite straight forward.

we have to use a Retrofit2 Response class for wrapping our data.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

```
@POST("some/endpoint")
Observable<Response<Data>> getData(...)
```

then we can manipulate it with a **flatMap**  and check the [Code](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#code--)

```
getData()
   ....
   .flatMap( response -> {
      if(response.code() == 200) 
        //do something
      else 
        //do something else
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you asked, but you can check isEmpty(), because as the body of a 204 is empty, retrofit won't emit any item and you'll receive an onComplete without any onNext.

Comment: Yep but how do I check "isEmpty", I guess I had to use a Response object for it, hadn't I?    Indeed, checking if is Empty won't be so useful If I had several 20x responses.